# Open source alternative for TestDrive.net 'Visual Studio add in' for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2005, nunit, testdriven.net

I searched about this in SO and dint find a post on this. Since TestDriven.net is ONLY free for *personal use*, is there any other open source visual studio add in available for running NUnit test cases?

Thank you.

NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TestDriven.net](http://testdriven.net/) is my #1 choice.  It's free for open source developers.  Get involved with OSS community.

You can use [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) that works with most unit testing frameworks. Here are some links about integration of Gallio and VS.

- [Link 1](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2008/04/gallio-integration-with-visual-studio.html)
- [Link 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2010/04/13/gallio-and-vs2010.aspx)

If you are [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) user (R# is not free but must have for any .NET developer), you can easily run your test from VS using this great tool.  [Here is how](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html).

Comment: But i cant use it in work place, right? That is why i'm looking for an alternative. I love TestDriven.net in my home :).

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing in the Personal licence that means it can't be used on commercial projects. It's "personal" in that the license is bound to the person who downloaded it; for example, you're not allowed to download it once and install it on your co-workers machines.

I do suggest that professional developers purchase a license (or more reasonably persuade their employer to). There is however always the free option for budget-constrained users.

You can read more on my July, 2006 post here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2006/07/10/EnterpriseAndProfessional.aspx

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This may have changed, because the free "Personal Licence" is "A nominal licence for students, open source developers and trial users. It is not intended for use within a commercial environment, except for evaluation purposes.". See the licensing information here: http://testdriven.net/purchase_licenses.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The makers of NUnit provide a Visual Studio add-in that is free to use.
Search for the "NUnit Test Adapter" in your Visual Studio Extension Manager.

[image: NUnit Test Adapter]

More information: http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2

Answer (score -2):

There are several. One of them is mbUnit http://www.mbunit.com/

Comment: I guess it is a unit test framework. It is not a TEST RUNNER. I was asking for something like UnitRun by JetBrains(which is discontinued - http://www.jetbrains.com/unitrun/) which helps us to run the tests right from Visual studio.

Comment: JetBrains discontinued it because a test runner is now part of resharper :(